# Maven package without clean creates shaded jar

Tags: maven

If I run "mvn clean package", maven creates two jars - a small one with "original" at the beginning and a larger one. I understand the large one is a "fat jar" with all the dependencies in it". That's the one I deploy to run.

If I don't clean and just run "mvn package" again, three jars are created, the same as the first two, plus one whos name ends with "-shaded".

Why the difference in behavior, would I ever want to deploy the shaded jar so my dependencies would not conflict with those from other packages?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>SMS Authenticator</name>
    <description>This is a provider for Keycloak for sending 2FA authentication codes via SMS</description>

    <groupId>CompanyX</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <aws.version>2.15.1</aws.version>
        <keycloak.version>11.0.3</keycloak.version>
        <maven-shade.version>3.2.4</maven-shade.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sns</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-logging</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-codec</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the maven output when I DONT clean:

```
C:\Users\bUserx\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\CompanyX\Repositories\Review\Development\CompanyX Utilities\Keycloak\Sms_Authenticator" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=57338:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.3.3 package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< CompanyX:keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator >----------------
[INFO] Building SMS Authenticator 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\CompanyX\Repositories\Review\Development\CompanyX Utilities\Keycloak\Sms_Authenticator\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) @ keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ---
[INFO] Including com.twilio.sdk:twilio:jar:8.8.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0359 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:sns:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:aws-query-protocol:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:jar:1.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:jar:2.15.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.4 from the shaded jar.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] annotations-2.15.1.jar, apache-client-2.15.1.jar, auth-2.15.1.jar, aws-core-2.15.1.jar, aws-query-protocol-2.15.1.jar, commons-io-2.6.jar, eventstream-1.0.1.jar, http-client-spi-2.15.1.jar, jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.1.jar, javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar, jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar, jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar, jjwt-jackson-0.11.2.jar, metrics-spi-2.15.1.jar, profiles-2.15.1.jar, protocol-core-2.15.1.jar, reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar, regions-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, sdk-core-2.15.1.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar, sns-2.15.1.jar, twilio-8.8.0.jar, utils-2.15.1.jar define 1 overlapping resource: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, twilio-8.8.0.jar define 2265 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.Twilio
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.Twilio$1
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Creator
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Deleter
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Fetcher
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Page
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Page$1
[WARNING]   - com.twilio.base.Page$Builder
[WARNING]   - 2255 more...
[WARNING] commons-io-2.6.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 130 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/NOTICE.txt
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderParser
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.Charsets
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.CopyUtils
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.DirectoryWalker
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.DirectoryWalker$CancelException
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.io.EndianUtils
[WARNING]   - 120 more...
[WARNING] commons-io-2.6.jar, javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 1 overlapping resource: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE.txt
[WARNING] jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 83 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.ClaimJwtException
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.Claims
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.ClaimsMutator
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.Clock
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionCodec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionCodecResolver
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionCodecs
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionException
[WARNING]   - 73 more...
[WARNING] jjwt-jackson-0.11.2.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 8 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.io.Deserializer
[WARNING]   - META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.io.Serializer
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.jackson.io.JacksonDeserializer
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.jackson.io.JacksonDeserializer$1
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.jackson.io.JacksonDeserializer$MappedTypeDeserializer
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.jackson.io.JacksonSerializer
[WARNING] jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 65 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionCodec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.AbstractTextCodec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.AndroidBase64Codec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64UrlCodec
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultClaims
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultClock
[WARNING]   - io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultHeader
[WARNING]   - 55 more...
[WARNING] jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 62 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.DecimalUtils
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module$1
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule$1
[WARNING]   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.PackageVersion
[WARNING]   - 52 more...
[WARNING] CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar define 36 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.IMarkerFactory
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.Logger
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.MDC
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.MDC$1
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.MDC$MDCCloseable
[WARNING]   - org.slf4j.Marker
[WARNING]   - 26 more...
[WARNING] jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 116 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF.versions.9.javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.Binder
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$1
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$2
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$3
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$4
[WARNING]   - javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder$5
[WARNING]   - 106 more...
[WARNING] javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 33 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.CommandInfo
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.CommandInfo$Beans
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.CommandInfo$Beans$1
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.CommandMap
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.CommandObject
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.DataContentHandler
[WARNING]   - javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
[WARNING]   - 23 more...
[WARNING] CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, sns-2.15.1.jar define 483 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/sns/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/sns/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - codegen-resources/customization.config
[WARNING]   - codegen-resources/examples-1.json
[WARNING]   - codegen-resources/paginators-1.json
[WARNING]   - codegen-resources/service-2.json
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.DefaultSnsAsyncClient
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.DefaultSnsAsyncClientBuilder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.DefaultSnsBaseClientBuilder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.DefaultSnsClient
[WARNING]   - 473 more...
[WARNING] aws-query-protocol-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 47 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-query-protocol/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-query-protocol/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.AwsEc2ProtocolFactory
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.AwsEc2ProtocolFactory$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.AwsEc2ProtocolFactory$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.AwsQueryProtocolFactory
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.AwsQueryProtocolFactory$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.interceptor.QueryParametersToBodyInterceptor
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.internal.marshall.ListQueryMarshaller
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.query.internal.marshall.ListQueryMarshaller$PathResolver
[WARNING]   - 37 more...
[WARNING] protocol-core-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 29 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/protocol-core/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/protocol-core/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.AbstractMarshallingRegistry
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.AbstractMarshallingRegistry$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.ExceptionMetadata
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.ExceptionMetadata$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.ExceptionMetadata$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.InstantToString
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.InstantToString$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.core.Marshaller
[WARNING]   - 19 more...
[WARNING] CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, sdk-core-2.15.1.jar define 460 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/sdk-core/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/sdk-core/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - VersionInfo.java
[WARNING]   - mime.types
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.ApiName
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.ApiName$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.ApiName$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.ApiName$BuilderImpl
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.BytesWrapper
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.core.ClientType
[WARNING]   - 450 more...
[WARNING] profiles-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 18 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/profiles/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/profiles/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.Profile
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.Profile$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.Profile$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.Profile$BuilderImpl
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile$Aggregator
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile$Builder
[WARNING]   - 8 more...
[WARNING] reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 4 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - org.reactivestreams.Processor
[WARNING]   - org.reactivestreams.Publisher
[WARNING]   - org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
[WARNING]   - org.reactivestreams.Subscription
[WARNING] auth-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 93 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/auth/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/auth/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AnonymousCredentialsProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain$BuilderImpl
[WARNING]   - 83 more...
[WARNING] eventstream-1.0.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 21 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.eventstream/eventstream/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.eventstream/eventstream/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.Checksums
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.Header
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderType
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderValue
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderValue$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderValue$BooleanValue
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderValue$ByteArrayValue
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.eventstream.HeaderValue$ByteValue
[WARNING]   - 11 more...
[WARNING] http-client-spi-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 61 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/http-client-spi/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/http-client-spi/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.Abortable
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.AbortableInputStream
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.ContentStreamProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullResponse
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullResponse$1
[WARNING]   - 51 more...
[WARNING] regions-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 259 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/regions/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/regions/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.DefaultServiceMetadata
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.GeneratedPartitionMetadataProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.GeneratedRegionMetadataProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.GeneratedServiceMetadataProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.MetadataLoader
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.PartitionMetadata
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.PartitionMetadataProvider
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
[WARNING]   - 249 more...
[WARNING] annotations-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 12 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/annotations/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/annotations/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.Generated
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.Immutable
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.NotThreadSafe
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.ReviewBeforeRelease
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.SdkInternalApi
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.SdkPreviewApi
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.SdkProtectedApi
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.annotations.SdkPublicApi
[WARNING]   - 2 more...
[WARNING] CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar, utils-2.15.1.jar define 81 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/utils/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/utils/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$Key
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$Key$UnsafeValueType
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.BinaryUtils
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CollectionUtils
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.utils.ComparableUtils
[WARNING]   - 71 more...
[WARNING] aws-core-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 70 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-core/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-core/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsExecutionAttribute
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequest
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequest$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequest$BuilderImpl
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration$BuilderImpl
[WARNING]   - 60 more...
[WARNING] metrics-spi-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 16 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/metrics-spi/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/metrics-spi/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.LoggingMetricPublisher
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricCategory
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricCollection
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricCollector
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricLevel
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricPublisher
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.MetricRecord
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.metrics.NoOpMetricCollector
[WARNING]   - 6 more...
[WARNING] apache-client-2.15.1.jar, CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar define 40 overlapping classes and resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/apache-client/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/software.amazon.awssdk/apache-client/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - META-INF/services/software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpService
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$ApacheConnectionManagerFactory
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$ApacheConnectionManagerFactory$1
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$Builder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$DefaultBuilder
[WARNING]   - software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheSdkHttpService
[WARNING]   - 30 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing C:\CompanyX\Repositories\Review\Development\CompanyX Utilities\Keycloak\Sms_Authenticator\target\CompanyX-keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0.jar with C:\CompanyX\Repositories\Review\Development\CompanyX Utilities\Keycloak\Sms_Authenticator\target\keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator-1.0-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: C:\CompanyX\Repositories\Review\Development\CompanyX Utilities\Keycloak\Sms_Authenticator\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.340 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-19T09:16:15-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What are you using? Spring Boot? And please show your pom.xml

Comment: I added the POM file to the question.  I'm just building from either InteliJ maven panel or a command prompt by running mvn.

Comment: Could you please try to do this again? I doubt that this is reproducible.

Comment: Every time I don't clean, it creates the shaded jar. I'll updated the original question with the maven output. Looks to me that if a jar exists, it tries to update it and finds that the objects already exits. I just wanted to understand what's happening and learn more about the process.